# How to remove keypress from input with jquery?

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know how can I remove keypress from input with jquery?

Example:

```
<input type="text" keypress="cleanMsg()" id="cleanMsg" name="cleanMsg">
```

How can I removed the keypress="cleanMsg()" from input by using jquery? Or anyway to replace keypress="cleanMsg()" to keypress="Msg()"??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean "how do you remove the 'keypress' attribute from the input", in which case this would work

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#cleanMsg").removeAttr("keypress");
    });
</script>
```

If you want to bind to a keypress, you should do it in the jQuery way (refer to the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keypress)), with this code the above attribute within the input tag is redundant

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#cleanMsg").keypress(function(){
            //do something here
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 32):

To further answer the general question, you can remove any keypress handlers added with Jquery with:

```
$('#foo').unbind("keypress");
```

unbind() without arguments removes all handlers.

Answer (score 5):

use unbind method

```
$('#foo').unbind();
```

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/